# How can I force magento to not to use SSL on hompage?

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I force magento to not to use SSL on hompage?

because I've created a featured product module and now magento is not displaying it and saying insecure content.

It works fine on UAT as there is no ssl certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to fix the insecure content being loaded by your module, you are getting this error by hard coding the http into your URI's. e.g.

```
<script src="http://www.yourdomain.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

You can fix this for example by linking to your file without the http, e.g.

```
<script src="//www.yourdomain.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

The browser will try to load the file from the same protocol the page is.

If you need to redirect the user from https to http you can put the following at the top of your .htaccess file (only an example so you should test, depends on whether you include the www in the domain or not as well).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```